# I need to process the urls on my pages before the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pushstate

Now, I'm using pushstate to create clean, custom urls on my website. My problem is when a page with a custom url is reloaded, the page returns an " Object Not Found! " error, understandably.

So, I need a way to process the urls using javascript (jQuery preferably) before the page is loaded so that on a page refresh, the correct content can be loaded.
Suggestions?

When a menu option is hit, this function is called, and it retrieves the info, pushes the new url as well as stores the navigation variables as the 'id' to allow navigation

```
function displayCategories(){

    var state = JSON.stringify(window.localStorage);

    if(localStorage.getItem("getMain") == "true"){
        If(localStorage.getItem("category") != "null"){

    $.post("/quizz/phpScripts/blah.php", {data : category}, function(data){
    if(data)
        $("main").html(data);

history.pushState({id : state}, '', '/quizz/quiz.html/'+customUrl);
});
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when the page is reloaded..I want the page to go to "quiz.html" which will then process the navigation variables and display the correct information.

Note. You may find some silly errors caused by auto correct on my phone. This particular function works perfectly.

Comment: You may want those objects to be observable and populate them with a deferred promise. It is hard to give you examples without seeing the code you are working from. But look into Knockout.js and the Deferred method in jquery.

Comment: See the edited question, I'd very much like an example. I hope I've provided enough information.

Comment: Just to be sure.  You are asking for a page that will take the given url and generate specific content based on the url? If this is the case there are two options, and only one is javascript. If the url is only www.mysite.com/things/stuff/ you will need Apache, or whatever web server to rewrite the url. The Javascript way, the url would have to be something like this: www.mysite.com/?things=stuff&foo=bar because javascript is client side, and url rewrites happen server side. With that in mind I will compose an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the url variables and go with it.

```
var getQueryStringParams = function() // This function should parse the GET variables in the url.
{
    var match, urlParams = {},
    pl = /\+/g,
    search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
    decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
    query  = window.location.search.substring(1),
    url = document.URL;
    while (match = search.exec(query))
    {
        urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    }
    return urlParams; 
};

var donFun = function(result) // Done function
{
    $("#main").html(result); 
};

var getStuff = function()
{
    $.ajax({url: "www.mysite.com/getStuff/"}).done(donFun);
};

var getJunk = function()
{
    $.ajax({url: "www.mysite.com/getJunk/"}).done(donFun);
};

var qsp = getQueryStringParams();
switch(qsp.someVar)
{
    case "stuff":
        getStuff();
    break;
    case "junk":
        getJunk();
    break;
}
```

For so little processing, I would not recoment jquery or knockout.  Keep your site light on code. Only go jquery if you can't avoid it. If your site has lots of changing variables and content I would take a close look at knockout.js. But something this simple does not need it.

```
// Alternate way using knockout

var content = ko.observable();
var getQueryStringParams = function() // This function should parse the GET variables in the url.
{
    var match, urlParams = {},
    pl = /\+/g,
    search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
    decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
    query  = window.location.search.substring(1),
    url = document.URL;
    while (match = search.exec(query))
    {
        urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    }
    return urlParams; 
};

var donFun = function(result)
{
    content(result);
};

var getStuff = function()
{
    $.ajax({url: "www.mysite.com/getStuff/"}).done(donFun);
};

var getJunk = function()
{
    $.ajax({url: "www.mysite.com/getJunk/"}).done(donFun);
};

var qsp = getQueryStringParams();
switch(qsp.someVar)
{
    case "stuff":
        getStuff();
    break;
    case "junk":
        getJunk();
    break;
}

// Your HTML would look like this
<div id="main" data-bind="html: content"></div>
```

The advantage to knockout is you have greater control over listening to your changing variables.  It is better for web apps with lots of changing variables

Comment: Thanks alot, this looks light. But I realize now that there can't be a client side solution for this since it wont work if the page doesn't exist. When someone enters this url "www.goodthings.com/othergoodthings.html/more/me"  and yet only "www.goothings.com/othergoodthings.html" exists there won't be any JavaScript since there isn't such a page. No? Would the server side solution you have work in this scenario. Where a 404 error leads to processing of the entered url??

Comment: Your web server can rewrite the URL before it gets to the destination.  How this is done depends what web server you are running. If you do not have control of the web server. I recommend going the GET variable path.  If you do have control of it and you know what it is I may be able to help you.

Comment: This depends on how much control I need. I've read somewhere that I could use a .htaccess file to do this, but all those posts are assuming we all know how to use these files. Please share the server side solution, that may be the best way at this point. The .htaccess file way has frustrated me so far.

Comment: I have not worked with the Apache .htaccess file in years.  You will want to look into:  
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (put some rewrite rule here)